# How to add innerHTML aspects when making using Turbo's datastore?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a project using turbo ([turbo360.co](http://www.turbo360.co)) and I'm trying to have the user signed in name appear in an  tag, however when I try to use the code:

document.getElementById('#header-name').innerHTML(visitor.name)

it doesn't have anything appear.

Here's how I declare the user:

```
    var visitor = {

        username: $('#input-username').val(),
        name: $('#input-name').val(),
        email: $('#input-email').val(),
        password: $('#input-password').val(),

    }
```

Anyone know why it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the wrong JavaScript syntax. You should remove the '#' symbol in 'document.getElementById' so you just have the name of the id.

Also, innerHTML is not a function, so you would not call it using 'innerHTML(visitor.name).' It is a variable, so you can do something like this with it:

```
const element = document.getElementById('header-name').innerHTML;
console.log(element);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

probably because visitor.name doesn't hold value. Check what value is returned by **$('#input-name').val()**. Also, the DOM insertion should occur after you have declared your visitor object.